# BackgroundWorker & Exceptions

Tags: c#, exception, backgroundworker

The [MSDN Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.dowork.aspx) says

> If the operation raises an exception that your code does not handle, the BackgroundWorker catches the exception and passes it into the RunWorkerCompleted event handler, where it is exposed as the Error property of System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs

But when I tried

```
_workers[i].DoWork += (s, args) =>
{
    throw new Exception("Error!");
};
```

I get Exception Unhandled error ... The code doesn't seem to go to `RunWorkerCompleted`. How are errors supposed to be handled?

### UPDATE

I have setup simple handlers

```
_workers[i].DoWork += (s, args) =>
{
    throw new Exception("Error!");
}
...
_workers[i].RunWorkerCompleted += (s, args) =>
{
    if (args.Error != null) {
        string dummy = args.Error.Message;
    }
    ...
};
```

The code never leaves `DoWork`

[image]

Comment: Do you have a RunWorkerCompleted handler?

Comment: Did you try the code without debugger?

Comment: Just did it, the code did goto the `RunWorkComplete` handler, except that it seems to keep "looping" there? See http://screenr.com/eCF. Since I cant use VS Debug, I dont really know why it keeps looping ... I just added 1 task

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If an exception is thrown and passes through user frames but is then not caught by user code, it is considered "user-unhandled".

So I think there are 3 possibilities:

- This is a [first-chance exception](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidklinems/archive/2005/07/12/438061.aspx) - so if you press F5, the exception will propagate as normal.
- Click "edit code" in the Exception Assistant. Then do some Edit and Continue to solve the problem.
- Go to Debug->Exceptions and de-select the "user-unhandled" column.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running through the debugger, Visual Studio will stop on exceptions in the `BackgroundWorker.DoWork` event handler rather than silently passing the exception to the `RunWorkerCompleted` event which is what happens when not in the debugger.

1) You can just hit F5 and continue execution to follow the exception (as RoadWarrior mentioned)

2) If that is too annoying, for `DoWork` don't use delegates/lambdas but use named methods and decorate with `[DebuggerStepThrough]` Attribute.  This will let the debugger ignore that method and not stop on exception so you can view the "normal" behavior of the Backgroundworker.

See: [Visual Studio 2008 Debugging - Skipping code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357891/visual-studio-2008-debugging-skipping-code)

Comment: Could you possibly explain why my Visual Studio is not stopping on exceptions thrown in the DoWork event, as your (1) states? There must be some setting I'm hoping

Answer (score 0):

I've done exception handling in BackgroundWorker yesterday. I didn't add any throw in Worker's DoWork handler. If exception happens, you will be able to get it in RunWorkerCompleted without throwing it. Just don't forget to cancel you Worker if exception occurs.

Comment: I thought when u throw, execution immediately ends? so I cannot set `Cancel = true` to my worker?