# How to Debug from last run state in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I am debugging an c# application. It has 2 parts. First part does a lot of computations, which will take almost 1 hour. Then it will call a method in the 2nd part, where I am getting an exception. I want to debug the exception. After the exception, the application crashes. So everytime I stert the debug process, I have to wait for 1 hour for the initial computation. Is there any way I can prevent this, like saving the state or something, so that I can continue debugging from this point?

Comment: Unit test! Mock the resulting data rather than waiting for it to be calculated.

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357891/visual-studio-2008-debugging-skipping-code

Comment: Of course there is, you just persist (e.g. write to file) the information in between steps. Courser you steps need to b separate functions, and some decent unit tests around them would be a good thing.

Comment: While it may not solve all of your issues you may want to look in to buying a edition of Visual Studio that supports [InteliTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264915.aspx) to help figure out what is happening leading up to the bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "saving the state" that I am aware of.
The program is in memory.
You would need to save the input to disk and then read the input.
If some of the input are objects (not values) you would need to serialize the objects.
[Object Serialization in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973893.aspx)

If your input is just values then you could hard code the values in a call to the method that is failing.

Even if some of your input is objects you might be able to hard code creating the object and hard code assigning the values.  But if some of the values are only assigned by running the long computation then that is not an option.

What is your problem with debugging the Exception?
Do you not know which line is throwing the exception?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is possible, however I would recommend breaking apart the long step from the short step so you can run them separately, see [Blam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22406428/80274) for more details on that.

If you need to make any changes to the program the following trick will not work if the DLL or EXE you are needing to modify are already loaded in memory, but maybe this will help you out. What you need to do is use a combination of a virtual machine and the [remote debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa.aspx).

Create a virtual machine in your software of choice and install the remote debugger on the VM image. Run your program up to the point it is almost finished with the long portion then take a snapshot of the VM according to the instructions of whatever VM software you are using. Now when you want to debug the last portion just reload the snapshot, attach your Visual Studio to the remote debugger, then you can start monitoring the application from that pre-setup state.

Answer (score 0):

You could generate a memory dump at the point when the program crashes.

On Windows 7, for example, you do this by right-clicking the process in Task Manager, then choosing "Create Dump File". Make sure to do this before you close any crash dialog etc.

You should then be able to use tools such as WinDbg or Visual Studio to repeatedly debug the process in the state it was when it crashed.

Saying that, I've always found debugging memory dumps to be fraught with difficulties. If you can modify the program to save the results of the long running computations to disk and read it in later to reproduce the crash I would try that first.